# How to make HTTP requests to an API controller with AuthorizedAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http

**Short story**

I have a Web API. I want to prevent unauthorized requests so I added `[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]` attribute to my `ApiController`.

How can I make requests to my own API from different apps in C# (from desktop app for example)?

**Long story**

I have a simple web app solution which contains 2 projects.

In `project1` users can sign in via username and password and do stuff. Code for signing users is as shown here:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetFromModelAsync(model); // just get user from DB
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, user.Code),
        new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, user.Role?.Name)
    };
        
    var id = new ClaimsIdentity(
        claims, "ApplicationCookie",
        ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType,
        ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);

    await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        new ClaimsPrincipal(id)); // I use httpContextAccessor cause I have this code not in controller
}
```

With this authentication, the user can easily access to any controller with attribute `[Authorize(Roles = "user")]`.

In `Project2`, I have Admin Web API which can change stuff that users did. I want to call this API from a desktop C# app and I also want that API to have an authorization requirement (`[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]` in my case).

For example, it looks something like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "user")]
public class AdminApiController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return Ok("Ok");
    }
}
```

And the question is: with such an authentication mechanism how should I make HTTP requests to such an API with `HttpClient`? The only way I know is to use `WebClient` and emulate authorization with `UploadValues` to special authorization form.

P.S. I tried setting HTTP `Authorization` header but it didn't work. Maybe the point is to use separate authentication mechanism for users and admins?

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: You should consider using JWT (JSON Web Token).

Comment: Search JWT authorization/authentication sample for Asp.net Core. You will find your answer.

Comment: Login just like other users would!

Comment: @CaiusJard, yeah, my bad, I didn't think that it could work. I made same thing for admins authentication (only removed redirection which was there for users) and this works just fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can follow the authentication mechanism **JWT(JSON web Token)** instead of cookies as the desktop app is a different environment that not use a web browser

User authentication scenario

1. the desktop app login to web API by userName and password param
2. if passed generate a token for the authenticated user and back it in response
3. when desktop app hit API action decorated by authorizing role via token

For a full example check this [Url](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/11/aspnet-core-3-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api)

Here is an example code in desktop app:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...

var client = new HttpClient();

var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Post,
        RequestUri = new Uri("https://api.domain.com/action"),
        Headers = { 
            { HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString(), "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" },
            { HttpRequestHeader.Accept.ToString(), "application/json" },
            { "X-Version", "1" }
        },
        Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(svm))
    };

var response = client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
```